# How to fix performance lag in canvas html5?

Tags: javascript, animation, html5-canvas, rendering

I am building a project where a user can type word in the input text and with the input value, canvas draws the particles onto the text. When the mouse hovers over the particles pushed back and comes back(core animation)

However, the performance is just terrible, it's way too slow and I have been looking up online and found stuff like frame rate, display ratio, getImageData, putImageData, new Uint32Array(), bitwise operator etc but after hours of trying different things I noticed I wasn't making any progress rather got stuck deeper

My codes are below, and if anyone can tell me where I should go about fixing it would be great.

in index.html

```
<canvas> </canvas>

<form>  
  <input class="text" type="text" value="touch me!" placeholder="type your message.."/>
  <div class="input-bottom"></div>
</form>
```

in app.js - I didn't include any code on form submit since it works fine

```
let canvas = document.querySelector(".canvas")
let canvasContext2d = canvas.getContext("2d") 
let canvasWidth = canvas.width = window.innerWidth
let canvasHeight = canvas.height = window.innerHeight

let form = document.querySelector('form')
let text = form.querySelector(".text")
let textMessage = text.value 

let mouse = {x: undefined, y: undefined}

function Particle(x, y, r, accX, accY){
    this.x = randomIntFromRange(r, canvasWidth-r)
    this.y = randomIntFromRange(r, canvasHeight-r)
    this.r = r
    this.color = "black"
    this.velocity = {
      x: randomIntFromRange(-10, 10), 
      y: randomIntFromRange(-10, 10)
     }
    this.dest = {x : x, y : y}
    this.accX = 5;
    this.accY = 5;
    this.accX = accX;
    this.accY = accY;
    this.friction = randomNumDecimal(0.94, 0.98)


    this.draw = function(){    
     canvasContext2d.beginPath()
     canvasContext2d.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, Math.PI * 2)
     canvasContext2d.fillStyle = "rgb(250, 250, 247)"
     canvasContext2d.fill()
     canvasContext2d.closePath() 

     // mouse ball
     canvasContext2d.beginPath()
     canvasContext2d.arc(mouse.x, mouse.y, 50, 0, Math.PI * 2)
     canvasContext2d.fill()
     canvasContext2d.closePath()
   }

   this.update = function(){
     this.draw()

     if(this.x + this.r > canvasWidth || this.x - this.r < 0){
          this.velocity.x = -this.velocity.x
      }

    if(this.y + this.r > canvasHeight || this.y - this.r < 0){
         this.velocity.y = -this.velocity.y
      }

    this.accX = (this.dest.x - this.x) / 300;
    this.accY = (this.dest.y - this.y) / 300;

    this.velocity.x += this.accX;
    this.velocity.y += this.accY;

    this.velocity.x *= this.friction;
    this.velocity.y *= this.friction;

    this.x += this.velocity.x;
    this.y += this.velocity.y;

   if(dist(this.x, this.y, mouse.x, mouse.y) < 70){
     this.accX = (this.x - mouse.x) / 30;
     this.accY = (this.y - mouse.y) / 30;
     this.velocity.x += this.accX;
     this.velocity.y += this.accY;
    }
  }
}

let particles;
function init(){
  particles = []

  canvasContext2d.font = `bold ${canvasWidth/10}px sans-serif`;
  canvasContext2d.textAlign = "center"
  canvasContext2d.fillText(textMessage, canvasWidth/2, canvasHeight/2)

  let imgData = canvasContext2d.getImageData(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight)
  let data = imgData.data

  for(let i = 0; i < canvasWidth; i += 4){
    for(let j = 0; j < canvasHeight; j += 4){
      if(data[((canvasWidth * j + i) * 4) + 3]){
        let x = i + randomNumDecimal(0, 3)
        let y = j + randomNumDecimal(0, 3)
        let r = randomNumDecimal(1, 1.5)
        let accX = randomNumDecimal(-3, 0.2)
        let accY = randomNumDecimal(-3, 0.2)

        particles.push(new Particle(x, y, r, accX, accY))
      } 
    }
  }
} 

function animate(){
  canvasContext2d.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight)
  for(let i = 0; i < particles.length; i++){
    particles[i].update()
  } 
  requestAnimationFrame(animate)
}

init()
animate()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you can consider reducing how much total work is going on for a full screen's number of pixels, for instance:

- reduce the canvas size (you can consider using CSS `transform: scale` to scale it back up if you must),
- reduce the number of particles,
- use a less expensive/less accurate distance operation like just checking horizontal distance and vertical distance between two objects,
- use integer values instead of floats (drawing to canvas with floats is more expensive)
- consider using `fillRect` instead of drawing arcs. (At such a small size it won't make much of a difference visually, but these are generally less expensive to draw- you may want to test if it makes much of a difference),
- even consider reducing how often you redraw the canvas (adding a `setTimeout` to wrap your `requestAnimationFrame` and increasing the delay between frames (requestAnimationFrame is generally about 17ms))

And some more small optimizations in the code:

- store `particles.length` in a variable after they are created so that you don't calculation particles.length on every `for` loop iteration in your `animate` function. But millions of calculations minus this 2048 isn't going to make much of a difference.
- only set the context `fillStyle` once. You never change this color, so why set it on every draw?
- remove the `closePath()` lines. They do nothing here.
- draw the particles onto an offscreen "buffer" canvas, and draw that canvas to the onscreen one only after all the particles have been drawn to it. This can be done with a normal `<canvas>` object, but depending on what browser you are working with, you can also look into [OffscreenCanvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OffscreenCanvas). Basic example would look something like this:

```js
var numParticles;

// Inside init(), after creating all the Particle instances
numParticles = particles.length;


function animate(){
  // Note: if offscreen canvas has background color drawn, this line is unnecessary
  canvasContext2d.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight)
  
  for(let i = 0; i < numParticles; i++){
    particles[i].update() // remove .draw() from .update() method
    particles[i].drawToBuffer(); // some new method drawing to buffer canvas
  }

  drawBufferToScreen(); // some new method drawing image from buffer to onscreen canvas
  requestAnimationFrame(animate)
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the help  If I could further on one of your suggestion above, reducing the size of the canvas works straight away although it results in a low resolution! so from this project https://jsfiddle.net/L8vtLqhu/1/ that I found on stack-overflow (he was asking about performance issue too) he fixed the code and it's super fast in the project in the link but he set the canvas.width and canvas.height to double the size of innerWidth and innerHeight (ratio = 2) could you explain how this works ?

Comment: A quick check on the resolution: make sure that the canvas width property matches it style.width and similar for height (otherwise you will get some weird scaling/stretching).

Comment: The jsfiddle link works a lot faster for me without the scaling (i.e., when I change the ratio to 1) because doubling the width and height he actually quadruples the overall pixel image data. He seems to be doubling everything then shrinking the output with CSS. The result should look nice but the performance will suffer. But you could consider trying this (in the opposite direction) say by setting the canvas CSS to `transform: scale(2);`

Comment: The biggest optimization improvement he is making is essentially doing the offscreen canvas tactic, but with raw data in a Unit32Array buffer instead of drawing to another canvas. Screen rendering is costly, so he stores all the pixel information in an object first, then draws it to the screen at once (instead of one particle at a time) using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/putImageData.

Comment: Thanks man! I updated my code for reducing the size of the canvas with scale it up with css https://jsfiddle.net/L6mnszhg/19/ however, it doesn't seem to work with the resolution at all. In my second update  https://jsfiddle.net/L6mnszhg/26/ I created numParticles and I can see it made it a bit faster but there's still a bit of delay in full screen. In the "howdy" example link, could you explain how he's utilising offscreen tactic ?

Comment: sorry the second link above is this one here https://jsfiddle.net/dgswhkLn/6/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210884/discussion-between-jinnn-and-tlong314).

Comment: Hey Mr., You are giving an overstatement that JavaScript can't do these large calculations. It is the processors work to do these things and it is capable of doing much more in just microseconds... You should not point at the amount of calculations. Instead, give some suggestions to optimize his/her code.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Bikram Kumar. I have edited my answer to remove any comments on general JS performance based on # of calculations, and to just focus on some potential optimizations in the code itself.